# Tomcat 501 on non-supported http verbs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

We are getting users hitting our Tomcat servers with custom HTTP verbs (like `UNSUBSCRIBE`). Unfortunately, when Tomcat encounters one of these, it returns:

> [501 Not Implemented](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E501.html)

Since it's a 500 error, it trips our monitor which wakes up the system guys. We're trying to figure out how to change this to a 400 level error and have it ignored by tomcat. I tried a `security-constraint` but I don't believe it's the right approach (and didn't fix the issue).

Is there a fix for this?  Using version 7.0.55 with SpringMVC 4.0

Comment: Why are you using custom HTTP verbs? That's a rather odd thing to do, given that it breaks compatibility with a lot of stuff and isn't RESTful.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html 501 is the appropriate server response to an HTTP verb that the server doesn't understand.  I don't think you actually want a different error code.  If your custom method isn't working, I'd bet you have some other problem.

Comment: As @IanMcLaird wrote, Tomcat's behavior is correct if it is going to reject the request on account of an unknown method.  On the other hand, if it serves the designated verb for some resources but not others (in which case the method is *known* to the server), then the correct response code for those it refuses to serve is 405.

Comment: In the event that 405 was a more appropriate response code, you could perhaps use a [Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/) to intercept and block the request before Tomcat slaps a 501 on the response.

Comment: @MelvinKicchi, we are using standard verbs, but people keep hitting our servers with non-standard ones, which then triggers the 501 which then makes ops unhappy.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Issue is it errors out at the Tomcat level before it even gets to the Spring app so I can't use any filters or interceptors.

Comment: Ahha!  I was about to ask.  This might actually be more of a question for ServerFault.  This sounds like somebody attempting an exploit of some sort, and might be better handled by some deep packet inspection before your tomcat server ever sees it.  Tomcat is doing the right thing here, and alerting your ops guys to a potential issue.

Comment: @Jason, if your web server generating the appropriate response in the event that people hit it with non-standard requests makes ops unhappy, then that's pretty much ops's problem.  Really, it's something they *should* monitor, because it probably represents unfriendly probes of your system.

Comment: Nevertheless, if your Tomcat is running in a hosted environment (e.g. behind Apache) rather than standalone then you could probably intercept the unwanted requests at the host server before they are ever passed on to Tomcat.  mod_rewrite should be able to do this, for example.